# How to hide jqGrid footer row when no records present

Tags: jqgrid, footer

I am using footer row to display Total of Amount column. If 0 records are found, I display message: "There are no records. If you would like to add one, click the "+" button below."
However the footer row is still shown with empty cells.

I tried method clearGridData as

```
grid.jqGrid("clearGridData", true).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

However that doesn't work. Shall I instead use

```
$(".ui-jqgrid-ftable").css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

OR you have any better recommendation?

Regards,

Abhilash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that it would be better to hide the div with the footer instead of the table (which have the class `ui-jqgrid-ftable`). The div have the class `ui-jqgrid-sdiv`. Usage of `$(".ui-jqgrid-ftable")` seems to me not good in case of usage more as one grids on the page.

I think that you can place hiding/showing the footer inside of `loadComplete` callback. You can test for the number of returned recorded and show the footer only if there are more as null records. The corresponding code could be about the following:

```js
loadComplete: function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $footer = $this.closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").next(".ui-jqgrid-sdiv"),
        records = parseInt($this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "records"), 10);

    if (records >= 0) {
        $footer.show();
    } else {
        $footer.hide();
    }
}
```

You can get minimal performance advantage if you would use `$(this.grid.sDiv)` instead of `$this.closest(".ui-jqgrid-bdiv").next(".ui-jqgrid-sdiv")`. The `grid` is internal property assigned to DOM of the grid. The `grid` property will be initialized during creating of the jqGrid and it will be used internally. It looks like

[image]

So you can change the above code to

```js
loadComplete: function () {
    var $footer = $(this.grid.sDiv),
        records = parseInt($(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "records"), 10);

    if (records >= 0) {
        $footer.show();
    } else {
        $footer.hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Oleg, you have been of great help always!